# What's the cleanest way to branch based on which conditional broke a while loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, structure, program-flow

Say I've got this loop

```
while(condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4){
     browseReddit();
}

if (!condition1){}
if (!condition2){}
if (!condition3){}
if (!condition4){}
```

It could be broken by any of the 4 conditions becoming false, and I would want to execute different code based on which one(s) it was. Ideally, I would not like to evaluate them all more than I absolutely have to. Assume `browseReddit()` forces us to evaluate them all again.

Putting an if chain after the loop is how I'm doing it currently. Is there a cleaner way? value brevity above all else in your answer.

Comment: Why do you think that's not the most efficient way? What are you trying to achieve? Do you just want a shorter or oneliner method? You could use a ternary style op.

Comment: What if the loop breaks out and both condition1 and condition2 are false? Do you want to deal with both? At the moment your code will only deal with the condition1 failing. You may not want those nested, and just use 4 if-ends instead.

Comment: @david I want to deal with each case, so that should have been 4 if-ends. Edited.

Comment: @drachenstern, I want to know if there is a way to write this in less code, but not a one-liner.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (1) {
    stop = 0;
    if (!condition1) {
        // condition 1 code
        stop = 1;
    }
    if (!condition2) {
        // condition 2 code
        stop = 1;
    }
    if (!condition3) {
        // condition 3 code
        stop = 1;
    }
    if (!condition4) {
        // condition 4 code
        stop = 1;
    }
    if (stop) {
        break;
    }
    browseReddit();
}
```

Comment: I guess I could have figured that out. _feels dumb_

Comment: @drachenstern: he might not want the code nested within the loop, I suppose, but why not?  It executes just as he desired.

Answer (score 1):

Final edit:

```
while((condition1||function(){alert("condition1 failed!");}()) & 
      (condition2||function(){alert("condition2 failed!");}()) &
      (condition3||function(){alert("condition3 failed!");}()) &
      (condition4||function(){alert("condition4 failed!");}())){
   browseReddit();
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/HjftT/3/

Comment: I didn't think all javascript engines did shortcircuit expressions

Comment: It should be written into the spec. Fixed it so it actually works now http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/HjftT/

Comment: Okay I think I'm about done :p I think this evaluates the conditions the minimum number of times, and also deals with multiple failures. You just need to be careful to make sure your anonymous functions don't return true.

Comment: JSLint also gets angry about creating functions in a loop, but it's boound to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the way you have in your current code sample, so that you don't exempt yourself from testing all four of your exit cases.